# App publishing in Google play store is delayed

Tags: android, google-play, apk, release

I want to Publish an app in playstore usually it takes two days, But now its been a week and app is not published? how do i solve this?

Comment: There really isn't much we can do to help you here.. Have you tried contacting Google and asking them if there are any errors with your release?

Comment: I contacted google with relation form page for this subject. But anyone answered to me for one week.

Comment: Our company has a critical update and the publishing also got delayed more than a week. Don't try to reach them out, they will tell you to keep waiting.

Comment: I am facing same isse, can you tell me how much time was taken to published?

Answer (score 1):

As per the new policies by google approval & publishing of app will take more time than past.

As stated [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282)

Google has updated the wording on the support page about how long it can take to publish an app. The page now says that review times can take “up to 7 days or longer” and “certain apps” may be subject to review times of 7 days or longer in “exceptional cases.” It’s not clear at this time what qualifies as “certain apps” or “exceptional cases.” We expect some clarification on this in the future.

[image]

As given above your app may be in exceptional case So it may take more than a week.
Now, wait for couple days.

Answer (score 1):

**Reduce the number of countries**

I have some apps in store. Those which set for 2 or 3 countries gets published within 3 hours or less. The others having more than 20 countries takes 4 or 5 days